# How to change the color of selected item of ListView (which is not a custom ListView)

Tags: android, listview

I know how to change the color of selected item of CUSTOM ListView. But i dont know how to change the color for normal ListView.

I had tried this :

> ```
> <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
>     android:listSelector="@drawable/listitemselector">
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/light_blue"></item>
</selector>
```

But this just changes the color of Entire ListView. I dont want to implement CUSTOM ListView just for selector color change. Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Post your adapter source please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with a shape as the background, instead of a simple color. Here's an example from one of my projects:

listselector_blue.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selector_state_blue"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

selector_state_blue.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#FF91B2FF"
        android:startColor="#4491B2FF" />

    <corners android:radius="10px" />

</shape>
```

Layout xml of the Activity with the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector_blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Bunch of Thanks for the solution. But i dont know why it is working. Why it works for 'shape' but not 'color' ???

Comment: Nice job but i am only able to see the selected color while i select the listview. Once if i finger up the listView it will show me normal color. I want to remail that index as selected. So what to do ?

Comment: You need to store the index or id of the clicked list row. Then you need to write your adapter so it draws the selected row with a different background. At least this is the way I usually achieve this.

Comment: @ZsomborErdődy-Nagy: Thanks. but after implementing this, if i scroll the list then will the selected index get changed by color or not ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The user clicks on a row, it gets selected. When the user scrolls around in the ListView after that, the selected row should remain the same. The click listeners on the rows won't be triggered by scrolling gestures.

Answer (score 2):

do not use this selector in the LISTVIEW tag..instead use this selector in your view for the list i.e. If you are using an xml for inflating your list's view (view of row ) just use this selector in that xml.

Comment: I know how to set it to the 'view of row'. But I should implement CUSTOM listView for this. I want to implement in NORMAL listview without inflating the view of listview row.