# how to change the font color of an item in a gridview (android)

Tags: android, gridview, fonts, textview

I have a gridview of letters for a wordsearch and I'm trying to get it so when you click on a letter it changes colour (which is working fine). But I also want to be able to change the font color back if the word is not correct.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {            
                Toast.makeText(TodaysPuzzleClass.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
                ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

This is the code so when I click on an item it changes color.

Using the coordinates from my toast is it possble to change the items color that way?

looking aroung i need to use the postion if the item then changes its color, but how do i do that?

Comment: use style like : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8443045/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10160299/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10448937/1168654

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: yea i use that in the item onclick, but how do i tell TextView V the position of the item that i want to change the color of?

for example if i click on item pos 1 and its not a word then change item pos 2 to a different color?

Comment: @BrianPeach you want to change the clicked item name color only.if u click item 1 to change color,all other items in default color and if you click item 2 change item 2 color only all other default color.